# Retrieving entry values through separate definition

Tags: python, if-statement, self

I'm having problems with the following code (I am a beginner in most things Python related) and am not sure how to use 'self' in this sense. I simply would like to retrieve any values given in the Entry boxes I create (bearing in mind there is a different amount of boxes depending on the if statement) when the start button is clicked.

I am however getting errors with 'self' not defined and such like. Is there any way of keeping the loops I've made and getting all the values back or is there a simpler way of writing this?

```
def ChBox(self, ch):

    column = 0
    if ch == "List":
        i = [0, 1, 2, 3]

        for i in i:
            ch_title = Label(ch_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            ch_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

            self.box = Entry(ch_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            self.box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)

    elif ch == "Inter":
        i = [0, 1]
        ch_title1 = Label(ch_frame, text='Min Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        ch_title1.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        ch_title2 = Label(ch_frame, text='Max Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        ch_title2.grid(row=0, column=column+1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        for i in i:
            self.box = Entry(ch_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            self.box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

def StartBut(self):
    value = self.box.get()

but1 = Button(frame_but, text='Start', command =StartBut(self))
```

UPDATE: In fact what I would like to do is return the box values without having to use classes or self if possible? I'm afraid that introducing classes and self etc now into my code would take too much time to rewrite it all..

Comment: show full code, with the class

Comment: The code is fairly long as it includes other stuff and the whole Tkinter interface. I don't have a class..I think that's where I get confused but don't know how to incorporate it to my code.

Comment: `I don't have a class.` self will work only with the class

Comment: if you don't have a class then using `self` makes no sense.

Comment: I don't understand how to incorporate a class, I tried very briefly but I still get 'self not defined'..Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just realised from reading comments that the `Button` class here is from tkinter.
This changes the nature of the question a little.

The `command` argument of the `Button` constructor is a callable with no arguments.
This means that if you just pass in a function, you can't actually pass any arguments to that function.
So if you want that function to have access to the but1 instance, then you will need to do something else.

One thing is to wrap the whole thing in a class, eg:

```
class MyButton(object):
  def __init__(self, frame_but, text):
    self.but = Button(frame_but, text, command=self.StartBut)

  def StartBut(self):
    value = self.but.box.get()
```

This will all depend on what you're trying to achieve, and how you are designing things.

Also, I'm not sure what the ChBox function is trying to achieve.

## Old answer

In python, "self" is usually the argument name used for class methods.

For example, if you have the following:

```
class Foo(object):
  def echo(self, a):
    return a
```

then when you write:

```
f = Foo()
f.echo(2)
```

the call to `f.echo(2)`, it gets translated into something like `Foo.echo(f, 2)`, so the instance `f` becomes the first argument, and hence is bound to `self`, and 2 is the second argument, bound to `a`.
In fact, you could actually call `Foo.echo(f, 2)` and it will do the exact same thing as `f.echo(2)`.

I'm not sure what your `Button` class is doing, but supposing it does something like:

```
class Button(object):
  ...
  def hit(self):
    self.command()
```

And what you want to achieve is to pass the current `Button` instance to the command, you should write instead:

```
class Button(object):
  ...
  def hit(self):
    self.command(self)
```

and when constructing an instance:

```
but1 = Button(frame_but, text='Start', command =StartBut)
```

You probably also want to rename the argument of StartBut, as `self` is normally only used as the first argument of methods:

```
def StartBut(button):
  value = button.box.get()
```

#### Sidenote

Understanding that `instance.method(args)` translates to `Class.method(instance, args)` will go a long way to helping you understand a lot of python semantics.

For instance, when learning to join a list into a string in python, you often see `' '.join(["hello", "world"])`. 
A lot of novices find this confusing and complain about the inconsistent syntax of python.
But really, this is the hugely consistent with the rest of python -- all it is doing is calling `str.join(' ', ["hello", "world"])`, and this should look more like the familiar form of join found in other languages. `' '.join(["hello", "world"])` is just a pythonic way of calling this method.

Comment: I thought I understood this and I tried but I get type error: object.__new__ takes no parameters

Comment: I have something in the Tkinter.py 'self.__callback(self.__value, *args). I really appreciate your help and patience as I really don't understand the class and self stuff. I've tried reading many things but it doesn't sink in.

Comment: I've read the new answer and tried it out but I have the problem now where my start button doesn't even appear in my interface..otherwise thank you very much for the answer! I'll try to get my head round it!

Comment: Is there a way of doing the same thing without using classes and self?

Answer (score 1):

`self` only makes sense within a class - it's the conventional way to refer to the "current" instance of the class, ie the one you're actually working with. Outside of a class, you would just use normal parameter names.

I don't know if it would make sense for your functions to be methods of the `Button` class. Otherwise, you should just pass your `Button` instance into each function explicitly.

(Also note `for i in i` makes no sense at all - you can't call an iterator the same thing as the list you're iterating over. Do `for x in i` or, even better, `for x in range(4)`.)

Comment: 'you should just pass your Button instance into each function explicitly.' I'm sorry but I don't understand this. I will try to incorporate a class but I'm not sure if it will conflict with other functions in my code. Thanks for the tip on the 'for i in i'!